# Carousel sliding effect using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, carousel

I want to create a carousel with a sliding effect as seen on http://www.mtv.com/, where if the user clicks on the slide, a new slide appears from the right and moves leftward. How can I do this?

Comment: Google 'JavaScript carousel' there are literally hundreds of them ready to use.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I do this with CSS.

```
<div class="slider">
   <div>Content area 1</div>
   <div>Content area 2</div>
   <div>Content area 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.slider {
    white-space: nowrap;
    oveflow:hidden;
}
.slider>div {
    white-space: normal; /* reset "nowrap" above */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    transition: margin-left 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.1, 0.5, 1.25);
    /* the above transition gives a neat little "bounce-back" effect */
}
```

Then my JavaScript can just do:

```js
theSlider.children[0].style.marginLeft = (-100*pageID)+"%";
// so 0% to view the first panel, 100% for the second, etc.
```

Side-note: The spaces between the elements will mess up alignment. Either put all your `<div>` content panels on one line (or, more specifically, make sure you do `</div><div>` between panels with no space), or use JS to strip out the spaces between elements.

Comment: why is there a ">" in .slider>div? I've never seen that notation before. Also, not sure why you have an array of children and pageID is a variable that iterates through the slides

Comment: @user3308889 It astonishes me how many people have "never heard of" something so simple as the "child combinator"... It basically means it only affects the `<div>`s that are immediately inside the `.slider`, but NOT any deeper-nested `<div>`s (for instance, if one of the slider panels contains a `<div>` somewhere in it)